# Regex is supposed to be right?

Tags: javascript, regex

How does this:

```
if (/[^\s\n{]\n*\z/.test(strsOfCode[i])
```

return false??

strsOfCode is `"const data = {message: 'Hello world',}"`
basically strsOfCode[i] is one line of code among many other lines of code...

I checked it in some regex checker as well

Comment: [Javascript doesn't support `\z`](https://regex101.com/r/HhlFgi/1)

Comment: Use `$`, which just means “end of string” in JavaScript. (Also, `\n` is contained in `\s`.)

Comment: Okay you're right, please make it any answer thank you @Toto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Javscript doesn't support `\z`](https://regex101.com/r/HhlFgi/1), use `$` instead.

Comment: @ProgrammingFreak: You're welcome, glad it helps. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted, [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)